# Timer with performance.now()

Tags: javascript

I want to realize timer using `performance.now` because `Date.now` depends on users clock (`performance.now` doesn't), and "`Date.now`-way" may crash the timer, when user changes system clock.

And I want to store timer in `localStorage`. When user close tab or browser and open it, timer have to resume.

**Important condition**: I want to take into account the time, when the browser/tab was closed. For example, user close browser, when timer value is 10 sec. After 10 sec user open the browser - timer value should be 20 sec.

This is the problem, that I faced.

This is code without using `localStorage`:

```js
const timerNode = document.getElementById('timer');
const initialTimestamp = performance.now();

setInterval(() => {
  const seconds = getSeconds(initialTimestamp);
  timerNode.innerHTML = seconds;
}, 200);

function getSeconds(initialTimestamp) {
  return Math.round((performance.now() - initialTimestamp) / 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id='timer'></div>
```

Is there any way to store timer in `localStorage` using `performance.now` and resume it in cases, that I mentioned above (and observing the condition)?

Or maybe there is another way to get UNIX timestamp, that is not depends on system clock?

To demonstrate problem with Date.now() run this code and  change system time, for example, set date to few days ago. You will see, that value of the timer is negative.

```js
const timerNode = document.getElementById('timer');
const initialTimestamp = Date.now();

setInterval(() => {
 const seconds = getSeconds(initialTimestamp);
 timerNode.innerHTML = seconds;
}, 200);

function getSeconds(initialTimestamp) {
 return Math.round((Date.now() - initialTimestamp) / 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id='timer'></div>
```

Comment: The only way to get a reliable time over a long duration is to query a server, I think.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "Date.now() depends on user's clock" when `Date.now()` returns a [UTC timestamp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)...

Comment: You can store the `seconds` value in in `localStorage`, and continue to update that, but as @DenysSéguret mentioned, it won't be very reliable.

Comment: @JaredSmith I update my question to demonstrate the problem with Date.now()

Comment: @HereticMonkey but in this case, when user close my site, or close browser, I can't update it

Comment: @RomanKonkin you can update `localStorage` value every `getSeconds` call or with `window.onbeforeunload` event.

Comment: You want to store `initialTimestamp` not the seconds.

Comment: @MaxSinev and what I have to store in `localStorage`? Seconds? In this case when user close browser, there will be no updating any more.
I was thinking about store **initialTimestamp**... But this is give me nothing in "close browser case", I think.

Comment: @JonasW. I was thinking about it. But what about case, when user close the browser? I can't calculate time relying on localStorage in this case

Comment: You can. Why shouldnt you?

Comment: @JonasW. do you mean something like this in my code?
`const initialTimestamp = localStorage.initialTimestamp || performance.now();`

Comment: @RomanKonkin what is problem to do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/ptc786ae/9/

Comment: My bad. I incorrectly asked a question, sorry. I will fix it.
I want to take into account the time, when the browser was closed. For example, user close browser, when timer value is 10 sec. After 10 sec user open the browser - timer value should be 20 sec.

Comment: @Max Sinev I've updated my question an added **important condition** (sorry again about it).
That's why solution, like you suggested, does not solve the problem

Comment: What is your use case for a timer that doesn't depend on the user clock settings? Everything on the client side can be messed with.

Comment: I get your point now but still second @Bergi, this is totally in the user's control if for no other reason than they could easily open up the console and overwrite your `localStorage` value to whatever they wished. There is no "foolproof" way to do this, not even keeping track server side. Just use `Date.now` since `performance.now` is not standard and do basic sanity checking on the backend.

Comment: I understand, that users can easly clean storage, and there is no bulletproof solution.

My use case is: if users OS, like Windows, just from time to time synchronize system clocks (and change it) - there will be problem with `Date.now()`. So, that's why I decided to use `performance.now()`.

Comment: @RomanKonkin No, there won't be a problem. When the page is opened, you just check whether the stored timestamp is in the past (the timer has already been exceeded while the page was closed) or in the future (and you should start counting down towards it). You can safely assume that when the system clock has been adjusted, that it is now the correct time and that it was changed only by a tiny amount.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you would use `localStorage` for this to persist across browser sessions.

You would use `setItem` to set the initial time and `getItem` to access it in new browser sessions. When the new browser session starts, you would check if a previous initial time existed. If it did, use it; if it didn't, create it.

```
var initialTimestamp = localStorage.getItem('initialTimestamp');

// If we previously set an initialTimestamp, convert it from string to number.
if (initialTimestamp) {
  initialTimestamp = parseInt(initialTimestamp);
}

// If we never previously set an initial timestamp, create one now.
else {
  initialTimestamp = performance.now();
  localStorage.setItem('initialTimestamp', initialTimestamp);
}
```